# Firebase Cloud Messaging stops working after a period of time

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Firebase Cloud Messaging set up on an Android app and an iOS app, everything works fine, *most of the time*. It works in the foreground, it works in the background, when you first install the app it generates an instance id token, and then it successfully adds it to our server (so it fires `onTokenRefresh()` which I have overwritten).

The problem is after an indeterminate amount of time (from experience it seems to be between 24 hours and a few days), I stop receiving notifications altogether, the app isn't uninstalled, the user hasn't deleted the app data, the app hasn't deleted the instance id token. It just stops working. On the Android app I can get it working again by logging out and logging back in, which seems to trigger a new instance id token to be generated, but the same can't be said on iOS, which isn't an ideal use case for the user anyway.

I have tried deleting the token manually by calling `deleteInstanceId()`  But it doesn't generate a new token until I close the app and re-open it (which doesn't happen at all when not deleting the token manually), this being on the Android app.

I've seen the Firebase documentation which says a new Instance ID is generated when one of the following happens.

> - The app deletes Instance ID
> - The app is restored on a new device
> - The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
> - The user clears app data.

I'm not sure what is meant by the second bullet point, but as far as I can tell, the token shouldn't be refreshed or at the very least being refreshed and my code not listening for it.

Why does it stop working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you receiving notifications from other iOS apps? I ask this bcz APNS doesn't seem to be functioning properly over past 2 months or so. So every time I have to reset my network settings and it would work properly. Now this problem only occurs when I am on wifi and not on cellular data.

Comment: android and ios have very different implementations. you should open different question one per platform. also on iOS notification-messages are different from data-messages.

Comment: @nh1402 have you solved this issues coz im facing same